# Create URL upon JavaScript submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, url, submit

I currently have a form with some JavaScript functions and localstorage.

I'm trying to get that when a user types a value into a textbox, the search bar changes the URL from "mysite.com" to "mysite.com/%userinput%". Then that user can send that link to someone else and that person will then see what the original user saw.

Comment: So you want to create some public/private data exchange between two or more users? For example, the first user sends his localstoraged text to your server and then he will receive some generated link, and a pair of a public and private password, so that everyone who opens a page like `http://mysite.com/?id=12345&pass=publicpassword` can read the latest version of that localstoraged text? Imho it looks like it's possible but not simple to do. Or is it some kind of a chat? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the URL after input.

As I understand from your question and comments, you don't want to load the URL, just change it, so try this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrP6U/2/show/)**: http://jsfiddle.net/GrP6U/2/show/

The code behind is:

#### JavaScript

```
var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
var theInput = document.getElementById('subj');

theForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
    var myurl = "http://jsfiddle.net/GrP6U/2/show/?input=" + encodeURIComponent(theInput.value);
window.history.pushState('', "Title", myurl);
    return false;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input id='subj'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using replaceState() instead of pushState()

Comment: @Thumbz, good input. I am just not sure of what OP means/needs/wants. I vote up your comment and he will also read it. Thanks.

Comment: Comments may disappear at any moment. It is better to include the information in the answer.